# How to configure postgresql to use openssl-1.1.1v?

Tags: postgresql, openssl, ubuntu-22.04

There is a server on ubuntu 22.04 LTS. postgresql version 12.4 and openssl 3.0 are installed (by default). For the project, it was necessary to install openssl version 1.1.1v, which was done according to this guide:

> https://www.faqforge.com/linux/how-to-build-and-install-openssl-from-source-on-ubuntu-linux/

After that, postgresql shut down. Error when trying to restart:

> Failed to start postgresql.service: Unit postgresql.service is masked

The database was reinstalled. But now the openssl version is 3.0 again, not 1.1.1v.
How to configure postgresql to use openssl 1.1.1v or reinstall postgresql using openssl 1.1.1v instead of openssl 3.0